# Как определить конец цикла foreach внутри него?

Tags: php

Добрый день!

```
<?
if (!empty($list6))
{
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?
        foreach ($list6 as $key => $post6) {
            if($post5->podkat.$post5->id == $post6->podkat)
            {
                ?>
                <li><a href="#"><?=$post6->name;?></a></li>
                <?
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?
}
?>
```

Здесь нужно сделать так, чтобы ul (открывающий и закрывающий) выводились, если условие

```
$post5->podkat.$post5->id == $post6->podkat
```

сработало, но ul вывелось по одному разу, а не в цикле.

Comment: @Iranda, ага.
@Cyclomedchik, а еще не размещаете ссылки на левые сторонние ресурсы без крайней необходимости: кроме того, что кому-то капает халявный рейтинг,   
главное - ресурс может оказаться оффлайн, тогда непонятно станет о чем был вопрос.

Comment: А почему бы не зделать так ?

    <?php
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pages`");
    while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {
          echo "Здесь будет выводится в цикле все что пожелаешь";
         }
      ?>

Answer (score 4):

Простейший вариант:

```
$lastVar = array_pop($your_array);

foreach($your_array as $key=>$value){
//do_something_with_vars
}

//do_something_with_last_var
```

Answer (score 4):

Еще вариант:

```
$len = sizeof($list6);
foreach($list6 as $key => $post6){
    --$len;
    if(!$len){
        // последний, стало быть
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сначала узнать кол-во элементов в массиве через дефолтовую функцию, а потом в конце поставить условие если они =, значит конец.

АВтор наверное хотел сказать как найти последний элемент ? а не как узнать закончился ли цикл ....

Answer (score 1):

Что значит:

> как определить конец цикла foreach внутри него

Этот цикл "автозавершаем", если можно так выразиться. И предназначен он в основном для прохода по коллекциям данных, поэтому он сам и завершается, когда достигнет последнего элемента коллекции.

Comment: Какие люди. =)
Ну да. Но именно из-за того что он сам завершается и приходится иногда чуток извратнуться. Кстати о проходе: число для прохода по коллекциям существует array_walk

Comment: @knes, первая буква - русская "A" =)